# Can Netlogo support 2D time series as forcings for turtles?

Tags: 2d, netlogo, spatial, agent-based-modeling, temporal

I am new to Netlogo, but want to use it for my next ABM. However I can't find any information on the ability of Netlogo to use 2D time series as drivers for the turtles. I know that Netlogo can use static information like bathymetry, but what about temperatures and spatial changes in temperature over time?

Can anyone point me in the right direction or describe if this functionality is present.

Edit: To expand on the issue. If I want a turtle to respond to rainfall, and I have a file with spatial information on the hourly rain fall, like a weather map, that changes in time and space. How would I go about loading this file? And if this is possible, which file types would be usable?

Comment: You can program just about anything in NetLogo. Your question is so general that it's hard to say anything specific except, why not try coding it, or some very simple form of it that's enough to get started with, and see where you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you want current decisions to be based on past information, then you only need to gather that information over time and analyse it.  The `stats` extension provides an easy way to gather past information and then to run regressions on it.  You might see if that serves your purpose.

You can find more information at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions, under Community Extensions.

Comment: it is not so much past infomation but I want the turtle to be able to respond to real world environmental parameters such as rain, wind ect. These parameters changes in time and space, which can be obtained from wether forcast systems. But how can this be implemented in the Netlogo model?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but NetLogo can respond to external information in at least two ways.  One is through the Arduino board and extension, with the board gathering the information and the extension reading it into NetLogo (as I understand it), and the other is to have the model continuously poll for a file containing new information and then having agents respond to it.  So, for instance, the model could periodically look for new temperature info in a file and respond. A question  specific to external inputs might catch the attention of someone more expert than I.